# Removing <p>Â </p> in HTML(HTML <sup /> tag affecting)

Tags: html

i WANT TO REMOVE `<p>Â </p>` from the html content..

here is the code:

```
   <span style="white-space: nowrap;">American Foundation<sup>®</sup><br />
```

after American Foundation `<sup>Â®</sup>` A is coming how to do???

any suggestion please..

Comment: Replace `®` with `&reg;`

Comment: sir how to hide <sup>â„¢</sup>

Comment: here i want TM ...

Comment: Use this `&trade;`

Comment: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes/html-code-tm.htm
check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `®`with `&reg;` and `â„¢` to `&trade;`

Comment: sir i want the small size R..but bydefault it will taking size big,,what should i do??

Comment: Write it in super script like `<sup>&reg;</sup>` and <sup>&trade;</sup>

Comment: <span style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 52px;color:white;"><strong>Family</strong>Connect<sup>®</sup></span>

Comment: Use this  `<span style="white-space: nowrap;">American Foundation<sup>&reg;</sup> and <sup>&trade;</sup><br />`

Comment: this is the first one

Comment: <span style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 52px;color:white;"><strong>Family</strong>Connect<sup>®</sup></span>

Comment: this is the second one

Comment: in first case the R size i want in 2nd case R size..i.e. i want both the R size same..here 2nd one is bigger then first one..so tell me what should i do

Answer (score 2):

you have to encode to `&reg;` or `&#174;`!
it is non latin character so you should use html entities! :)

---

**[EDIT] after comments:**

sir how to hide <sup>â„¢</sup> – Mr. Manoj Kumar 4 mins ago

set your document encoding to utf-8. And depending on your programming language you have to output utf-8 also to your document. – antoni 3 mins ago    edit

how..???can you tell me – Mr. Manoj Kumar 2 mins ago

here i want TM instead of <sup>â„¢</sup> – Mr. Manoj Kumar 1 min ago

use `&#8482;` for `tm`!

Comment: sir how to hide <sup>â„¢</sup>

Comment: set your document encoding to utf-8. And depending on your programming language you have to output utf-8 also to your document.

Comment: here i want TM instead of <sup>â„¢</sup>

Comment: use &#8482; for tm!

Comment: I was first giving same answer. not nice - whatever ;)

Comment: i appreciate with your answer..because it working fine..thanks